# General solution of equation $\tan(3x - \frac{\pi}{4}) = \tan(x)$

Tags: trigonometry

I'm looking for the general solution to $$\tan(3x-\pi/4)=\tan(x).$$ $\pi/8$ is a solution by inspection but it does not seem to lead to the general solution given: $(4n+1)\pi/8$.

This given solution is correct (graphically, using Desmos.com). Expanding out using $\tan(a+b)$ and $\tan(3x)$ leads me to a degree $4$ polynomial with no obvious solutions. I'm probably repeatedly doing something silly. Any ideas?

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for formatting your math.

Comment: I edited the question, so you can see what are the most basic MathJax signs.

Answer (score 2):

$$\tan \alpha=\tan \beta \implies \alpha = n\pi +\beta ; n \in \mathbb Z$$
Therefore :$$\tan(3x-\pi/4)=\tan(x) \implies 3x-\pi/4=n\pi +x \implies x=\frac{(4n+1)\pi}{8}$$

Answer (score 2):

$\tan(\alpha) = \tan(\beta)$ if and only if $\alpha = \beta + n\pi$, with $n$ an arbitrary integer ($ n \in \Bbb Z$). Thus you just have to solve $3x-\pi/4 = x + n\pi$ ...